# display string in new activity on image click

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a gridview with images where you can click on an image and a new activity will pop up displaying the image. What I want to do now is have text also display above the image that is specific to the image. Here is what I have so far, keep in mind, the pictures explaining what I want is basic XML.

- [Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y87sv.png)
- [Example Picture #1 of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BUPS.png)
- [Example picture #2 of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU23v.png)
- [Image View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUfB4.png)
- [Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHTBO.png)
- [Single View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sQcM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to keep related data together, I would recommend using a tuple. More specifically a `Pair<Integer, String>()` in your case.

So for the most straight forward solution I could give you:

Replace your `Integer[]` in your ImageAdapter with

```
public ArrayList<Pair<Integer, String>> mThumbIdsAndText = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Pair<>(R.drawable.shrek1, "shrek1 text"),
            new Pair<>(R.drawable.shrek2, "shrek2 text"),
            new Pair<>(R.drawable.shrek3, "shrek3 text"),
            new Pair<>(R.drawable.shrek4, "shrek4 text"),
            new Pair<>(R.drawable.shrek5, "shrek5 text"),
            new Pair<>(R.drawable.shrek6, "shrek6 text")
            ));
```

And then in your SingleView you can do

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIdsAndText.get(position).first);
// some text view that you'll have to create
textView.setText(imageAdapter.mThumbIdsAndText.get(position).second);
```

---

---

---

---

Honestly though I would recommend moving this `ArrayList` to your MainActivity and instead of putting the position in the Intent, you would

```
Integer thumbId = mThumbIdsAndText.get(position).first;
String text = mThumbIdsAndText.get(position).second;
i.putExtra("thumbIdExtra", thumbId);
i.putExtra("textExtra", text);
```

and then in the SingleView you are just being given the one image and its text, so you can do

```
Integer thumbId = i.getIntExtra("thumbIdExtra");
String text = i.getStringExtra("textExtra");

imageView.setImageResource(thumbId);
// some text view that you'll have to create
textView.setText(text);
```

Then you can pass the ArrayList to the ImageAdapter and then you would replace things like mThumbIds.length with mThumbIds.size and mThumbIds[position] with mThumbIds.get(position)

This way you don't need to create an instance of the ImageAdapter in your SingleView, simply to get the image that you want to display